# Navbar works only in first click, in second does not work and it wont go back

Tags: html, css, nav

I am developing a website and on the navbar if I click on one navbar item it works (sends me to that page) but if I click on the other items it wont work (it wont go to another section) and it wont go back either. This happens for every item!

Here are the files:

[image]

Here is the html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <section class="sub-header">

        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
            <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
                <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">COURSE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
        </nav>
        <h1>Our Courses</h1>


    </section>

    <section class="course">
        <h1>Courses We Offer</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget iaculis dui, quis dapibus diam. Etiam
            tellus erat, consectetur eget eros sit amet, tincidunt consectetur erat.</p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="course-col">
                <h3>Intermediate</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget iaculis dui, quis dapibus
                    diam.
                    Etiam
                    tellus erat, consectetur eget eros sit amet, tincidunt consectetur erat. </p>
            </div>

            <div class="course-col">
                <h3>Degree</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget iaculis dui, quis dapibus
                    diam.
                    Etiam
                    tellus erat, consectetur eget eros sit amet, tincidunt consectetur erat. </p>

            </div>

            <div class="course-col">
                <h3>Post Graduation</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget iaculis dui, quis dapibus
                    diam.
                    Etiam
                    tellus erat, consectetur eget eros sit amet, tincidunt consectetur erat. </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="facilities">
        <h1>Our Facilities</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent cursus nulla consequat, congue tellus
            in,
            dictum massa. Proin facilisis arcu erat, ut euismod ex fringilla at.</p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="facilities-col">
                <img src="./img/library.png">
                <h3>World Class Library</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent cursus nulla consequat, congue
                    tellus in, dictum massa. Proin facilisis arcu erat, ut euismod ex fringilla at.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="facilities-col">
                <img src="./img/basketball.png">
                <h3>Largest Play Ground</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent cursus nulla consequat, congue
                    tellus in, dictum massa. Proin facilisis arcu erat, ut euismod ex fringilla at.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="facilities-col">
                <img src="./img/cafeteria.png">
                <h3>Tasty and healthy food</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent cursus nulla consequat, congue
                    tellus in, dictum massa. Proin facilisis arcu erat, ut euismod ex fringilla at.</p>
            </div>
        </div>



    </section>



    <section class="footer">
        <h4>About Us</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> Praesent cursus nulla consequat, congue
            tellus
            in,
            dictum massa <br>. Proin facilisis arcu erat, ut euismod ex fringilla at</p>
        <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-square-instagram"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-square-twitter"></i>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script>
        var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

        function showMenu() {
            navLinks.style.right = "0";
        }
        function hideMenu() {
            navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
        }


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in the `href` attribute you must to specify where the link is going to:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="/course.html">COURSE</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```